# Configuring Wildfly datasource for a JHipster application

Tags: spring, jpa, jhipster, wildfly-9

I am to deploy a JHipster application to Wildfly (v. 9.0.2) servers and need to use JNDI data sources.

The basic connection setup is pretty straightforward: I set up new data source in Wildfly's `standalone.xml` to mimic the out-of-the-box `ExampleDS`, then included a reference to it into `application-dev.yml` and slightly modified `DatabaseConfiguration.java`. Now, that works well.

The problem is that `application-xxx.yml` files also contain JPA configuration, and I don't know where to stick it into Wildfly (I guess it must be in Wildfly).

To be more precise, I have no idea where to move the following JPA parameters:

```
jpa:
    database-platform
    database
    openInView
    show_sql
    generate_ddl
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto
        naming-strategy
    properties:
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache
        hibernate.generate_statistics
        hibernate.cache.region.factory_class
```

I know that Wildfly advises this to be defined in persistence.xml, in which case, can I just drop it into the project?

Thank you in advance.